# How to do ternary operator when grouping by in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have table that looks like:

```
| name | feature |
|------|---------|
| bob  | t       |
| bob  | f       |
```

`name` is a text column and `feature` is a boolean. I want to run a query so that if a name has `t` present in its corresponding feature values, the name gets assigned `t`, otherwise `f`. Something like

```
SELECT name, CASE WHEN 't' in ARRAY_AGG(feature) THEN 't' ELSE 'f' END AS custom_feature 
FROM table 
GROUP BY name
```

Thus producing:

```
| name | custom_feature |
|------|----------------|
| bob  | t              |
```

What is the best way to do this in Postgres?

Answer (score 3):

There are boolean aggregates [`bool_and()` and `bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html).

You can write your query this way:

```
SELECT name, bool_or(feature) AS custom_feature 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you need something like this:

```
select  distinct on(name) name, feature 
from table 
order by name, feature desc
```

If feature column is nullable, then you can:

```
select  distinct on(name) name, coalesce(feature, false) 
from table 
order by name, feature desc nulls last
```